# How to turn off keyboard sound on Nexus 7 2nd gen

Tags: nexus-7

I already have touch sound turned off, but still hear keyboard sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will fix it:

Go to Settings, Language & input, Google or Android keyboard settings then untick the box next to "Sound on keypress".

Comment: it's Google keyboard, not android in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings, sound and notification, other sounds, touch sounds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this answer may be valid in some cases, but in this one the question specifically says that "touch sounds" are already off.